# Office 365 Graph API $top not being honoured on delta queries

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

The Office 365 Graph API documentation suggests that $filter and $top operations should be supported when used together on a delta query...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages#track-message-changes-in-a-folder

However, when executing a query that uses both $filter and $top such as this:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailfolders/AAMkADQ3MDg1NWRmLTUxMGQtNDRiMi1iMGE4LTAzMzdjNGRiYTIxNQAuAAAAAADEPuholyn_QpUTcq2qMEH4AQBScDrPb_rMTZOocc5vRCTLAAAAAAEMAAA=/messages/delta?$filter=receivedDateTime%20ge%202017-04-01T00:00:00Z&$top=1000

We find that the $top value is not applied and the default value of 10 results per page is used. However the $filter has been applied correctly.

When testing without the $filter statement, we find the $top value is applied as expected.

Is this a bug in the Graph API or am I misunderstanding something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My main concern is that the "value" in the $filter might not be escaped, or that there may be other escaping issues.  Can you post the raw request?  Is the $filter working even when $top is included?

Comment: I've updated my original post to contain the raw request URL. The $filter is working fine, just the $top value that is not being applied.

Comment: I'm wondering if $top=999 would solve the problem.  Documentation is kind of confusing on the issue, but 999 seems like the magic number.

Comment: Still no luck - I've tried $top=999 and I'm still only getting back 10 items per page

Answer (score 1):

I could not get output using `$top` parameter with delta.

But the optional `odata.maxpagesize` header mentioned in the same doc seems to be working.

You can try adding this to your request headers. Prefer:

```
odata.maxpagesize=1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no luck I'm afriad. I've tried using this header and it makes no difference to the page size.

Answer (score 0):

Was also having issues w/ $top on /messages/delta.  Not only does it not work, found $top actually breaks /messages/delta. If using $top on a folder with say 1000 messages in it, /messages/delta will return 10 messages w/ a skip token.  Pass that skip token back in, you'll get 0 messages w/ a delta token.  Pass that delta token back in and you'll get 0 messages again.  Take off the $top in the original call and you'll be able to pagination through all 1000 messages.  It seems that $top isn't specifying how many responses to get back but rather how far in the list the API will look.